# Consecutive elements of a vector in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I am trying to display some value of n consecutive numbers of a vector (in this example, vector x).

```
x = [1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     1
     1
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0];
```

For example, I may want the first 3 values of 4 consecutive numbers which would be (3 values of 4 bits each):

```
1111
1100
0011
```

I may want the first 4 values of 2 consecutive numbers which would be (4 values of 2 bits each):

```
11
11
11
00
```

`x` is a double array. What would be an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to reshape `x` to a matrix with your desired number of bits per value as the number of rows (MATLAB is column-major). For example, to get 4-digit values:

```matlab
t = reshape(x,4,[]);
```

This will only work if the length of `x` evenly divides into 4. You could first crop `x` to the right number of elements to avoid errors where the length is not evenly divisible:

```matlab
t = reshape(x(1:4*3),4,[]);
```

Now the transposed matrix `t`, converted to a string, looks like your desired output:

```matlab
c = char(t.' + '0');
```

The output is a 3x4 char array:

```
    '1111'
    '1100'
    '0011'
```

You can convert these binary representations back to numbers with `bin2dec`:

```matlab
b = bin2dec(c);
```

The output is a 3-element double vector:

```
    15
    12
     3
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I want to write it in a text file, what would the code look like? What I have now is this :

fileID = fopen('readmesetonly.txt','w');
......
fclose(fileID);

I want to write the file in binary as is.

Comment: You can write out the char array using `for i=1:3, fprintf('%s\n',c(i,:)), end`.